# Converting strings in input file

Tags: string, unix

I have a text file `file1.txt` on Unix. I'd like to produce another file `file2.txt`, in which I change all groups of lines that has this format (taken from a multiple-choice exam)

```
a. [first choice]
b. [second choice]
c. [third choice]
```

to

```
[first choice] [second choice] [third choice]
```

How could I do that?

**EDIT**: An example is

```
What is the value of three plus five?
a. six
b. seven
c. eight

This line is not so relevant.
blah blah

What is the capital of England?
a. London
b. Birmingham
c. New York
```

It should be converted to

```
What is the value of three plus five?
six seven eight

This line is not so relevant.
blah blah

What is the capital of England?
London Birmingham New York
```

Comment: is your input complete? so the file2 will contain only one line? just join all [...] together? How does the "group" in file1 look like?

Comment: @Kent Sorry, seems like my description wasn't clear. Please see my example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this one-liner should work for you:

```
 awk '{if($0~/^[a-z]\. /){gsub(/^[a-z]\. /,"");printf "%s ",$0;s=1;next;}else{if(s)print "";print $0;s=0}}' file1
```

test

```
kent$  cat exam
What is the value of three plus five?
a. six
b. seven
c. eight

This line is not so relevant.
blah blah

What is the capital of England?
a. London
b. Birmingham
c. New York

kent$  awk '{if($0~/^[a-z]\. /){gsub(/^[a-z]\. /,"");printf "%s ",$0;s=1;next;}else{if(s)print "";print $0;s=0}}' exam
What is the value of three plus five?
six seven eight 

This line is not so relevant.
blah blah

What is the capital of England?
London Birmingham New York
```